# Excel power query column split using regex

Tags: powerquery

I'm provided with a csv file each month that is well structured except for one field (Narration).  It appears to be another table dumped into one field:

```
Type, Quantity, Price, Narration, Date
NS, 35.63, 1.23, TRANSACTION DATE:041119: LOCATION:ALPHA ST RECEIPT:37925663 CARD:8019789478947894 Card Reference:ABC123  198127 Odometer:123456 RFT Amount:0.00, 4/11/2019
NS, 12.12, 1.99, TRANSACTION DATE:051119: LOCATION:BETA ROAD RECEIPT:123456 CARD:1234567898765432 Card Reference:DEF456  198127 Odometer:654321 RFT Amount:0.00, 8/11/2019
```

I'd like to normalise this data into a single flat table. 
I can't split using a delimiter as both header and data components contain spaces. 
Regex would be my usual approach - but I'm not familiar enough with Power Query

Note the extra colon after the "TRANSACTIONDATE:041119:" record.  This is consistently present in all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your example and came up with this:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("YOUR PATH"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Type", type text}, {" Quantity", type text}, {" Price", type text}, {" Narration", type text}, {" Date", type date}}),
    #"Inserted Text Between Delimiters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TRANSACTION DATE ", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([#" Narration"], ":", ":"), type text),
    #"Inserted Text Between Delimiters1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters", "LOCATION", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([#" Narration"], ":", " ", 2, 1), type text),
    #"Inserted Text Between Delimiters2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters1", "RECEIPT", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([#" Narration"], ":", " ", 3, 0), type text),
    #"Inserted Text Between Delimiters3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters2", "CARD", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([#" Narration"], ":", " ", 4, 0), type text),
    #"Inserted Text Between Delimiters4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters3", "Card Reference", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([#" Narration"], ":", " ", 5, 2), type text),
    #"Inserted Text Between Delimiters5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters4", "Odometer", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([#" Narration"], ":", "R", 6, 0), type text),
    #"Inserted Text After Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters5", "RFT Amount", each Text.AfterDelimiter([#" Narration"], ":", 7), type text)
in
    #"Inserted Text After Delimiter"
```

I did this by adding Columns from Examples using the UI.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Power Query does not support regular expressions. So you may need to explore a different approach.

- If the fields `"TRANSACTION DATE", "LOCATION", "RECEIPT", "CARD", "Card Reference", "Odometer", "RFT Amount"` are the only ones that will ever be present and are the only ones you need to extract, maybe the code below will work for you.
- The code basically attempts to find the first occurrence of each of these fields within each `Narration` and arrive at a list of text values; each of which are assumed to be of the structure: `<fieldName>:<fieldValue>`.
- The logic could be changed depending on the strictness required and how much the values in the `Narration` column vary in terms of structure. (For example, could use `Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to make case-insensitive searches for field names.)

---

```
let
    file = Text.ToBinary(
"Type, Quantity, Price, Narration, Date
NS, 35.63, 1.23, TRANSACTION DATE:041119: LOCATION:ALPHA ST RECEIPT:37925663 CARD:8019789478947894 Card Reference:ABC123  198127 Odometer:123456 RFT Amount:0.00, 4/11/2019
NS, 12.12, 1.99, TRANSACTION DATE:051119: LOCATION:BETA ROAD RECEIPT:123456 CARD:1234567898765432 Card Reference:DEF456  198127 Odometer:654321 RFT Amount:0.00, 8/11/2019"),

    csv = Csv.Document(file, [Delimiter=",", QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv]),
    promoted = Table.PromoteHeaders(csv, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    fieldsToExtract = {"TRANSACTION DATE", "LOCATION", "RECEIPT", "CARD", "Card Reference", "Odometer", "RFT Amount"},
    extractFields = (someText as text) as record =>
        let
            positions = List.Transform(fieldsToExtract, each Text.PositionOf(someText, _ & ":", Occurrence.First)),
            splitterFunc = Splitter.SplitTextByPositions(positions),
            fieldNamesAndValues = splitterFunc(someText),
            fieldNames = List.Transform(fieldNamesAndValues, each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ":")),
            fieldValues = List.Transform(fieldNamesAndValues, each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ":")),
            recordsPresent = Record.FromList(fieldValues, fieldNames),
            selected = Record.SelectFields(recordsPresent, fieldsToExtract, MissingField.UseNull)
        in recordsPresent,
    recordsExtracted = Table.TransformColumns(promoted, {" Narration", extractFields, type record}),
    expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(recordsExtracted, " Narration", fieldsToExtract)
in
    expanded
```

which gives me:

[image: Output]

---

Small details. I used a delimiter of `,` (instead of `,`) and hence the headers in my table began with a leading space. This is also why the code above refers to a column named `Narration`. Can be fixed with `Text.TrimStart` or `Text.Trim`, or passing a multi-character delimiter when parsing.

Also, I couldn't tell if `RFT` was part of the previous field's value, or part of the current field's name. I arbitrarily included it in the name as `RFT Amount`. If this is not right, you can edit it in the code.